# magento server move produces Cannot redeclare class Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options

Tags: magento

I am trying to move magento site to another server. I have edited local.xml and changed core_config_data table path and urls. When I take link, I am getting following error.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options in /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 35

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you cleared cache..?If yes,then you have missed something or misconfiguration in core_config_data table..Check your table again..

Comment: Yes,cleared cache already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last we figured out the issue. The server had eAccelerator module with php and which was causing issue. We have disabled eaccelerator module and magento site loads fine.